# How does <merge> tag work internally

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, merge

I am trying to understand how does `<merge>` tag internally work. I have studied some examples using `View Hierarchy` tool. So I understand basic using and how does it work on higher level, but I wanna to study more about this tag and inflating views in general.
So let's consider some simple layouts
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/titlebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/some_text"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And of course **titlebar.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/chrome" />
</merge>
```

In this case we have following result.
[image: First]

Let's change our **titlebar.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/some_text"
    android:src="@drawable/chrome" />
```

The result is really forthcoming.
[image]

Let's do more changes in our activity_main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/titlebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bug"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:padding="10dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

And in **titlebar.xml** I left everything the same.

So in this case we have some weird things
1. Now our root layout is `LinearLayout`. We have specified nonexistent attribute `android:layout_below="@+id/some_text"` in titlebar file

2. In the same line we have another issue `@+id/some_text` doesn't exist anymore, now we have `@+id/bug`.
   Let's look at the result

[image]

Here I have some questions :

1. We are can use any attribute (for any layout) in merged file,but if the viewgroup(layout) where this part is included (in our case activity_main.xml) doesn't have such attributes, what how this situation is solved, just ignored as we can see in result ?
2. We have hardcoded id of view above imageview,it works if id is exists, but if it doesn't , as we can see in result it is also just being ignored

So I have already written a lot. 
To sum up, where works of XML parser exactly with merged and include tags is described, also it will be good to know where sources of XML parser is located, to look through it.

I will be grateful for everyone who read this line and can suggest something or give advice.

Thx in advance.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `<include>` tag includes both layout_width and layout_height, it will override all of the root view's (of the file it is including) layout parameters.

A `merge` is a way to avoid an additional depth in the view hierarchy - an XML layout file must only have 1 root - so it must either have a single `View`, a `ViewGroup` which can include additional `View`s or a `<merge>`. When you're including a layout with multiple `View`s inside a `ViewGroup`, you may be adding extra unneeded complexity to your hierarchy - for example, 2 vertically orientated `LinearLayout`s may not be required. The `merge` allows you to remove the extra `ViewGroup`, and merge its `View`s into the `ViewGroup` where it is included.

Including a layout with a `merge` with a single `View` is the same as just including a layout with the single `View` directly, except that with the `merge` there isn't a 'root view' of the layout, so the `include` will not override its layout parameters (I believe).

When a `View` or `ViewGroup` is inflated into a `ViewGroup` which doesn't support the layout parameters that the child specifies, the parameters are just dropped. This occurs when including or inflating (using a layout inflater).

If a child `View` or `ViewGroup` is added to a `ViewGroup` (using addView), it is possible that the child already has layout parameters assigned, and if they aren't compatible with the `ViewGroup` it is being added to, it may result in a class cast exception later on during measuring / layout.

Your second question is to do with `RelativeLayout`s layout rules, and its behaviour can be defined using `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing`